# Search for Outlook Email based on Sender, Subject, and Today's Date

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-filter

I am supposed to receive an email with the subject `"Testing Protocol"` from `"BobSmith@company.com"` every day.

Is there a way to search my Outlook Inbox to determine if an email has come through with that subject and that sender for the current day? Id like a simple "Yes" or "No" to be placed in cell A1 of "Control" if it has or has not been received today.

Below is what I have tried to come up with on my own using previous questions with no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated. `EmailSubject = "Testing Protocol"`

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim EmailSubject As Range
Set EmailSubject = Sheets("Control").Range("EmailSubject")

If Item.Class = olTask Then
    If InStr(Item.Subject, EmailSubject) > 0 Then
        ReminderUnreceivedMail
    End If
End If

End Sub

Sub ReminderUnreceivedMail()

Dim Itms As Items
Dim srchSender As String
Dim srchSubject As String

Set Itms = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
srchSender = "BobSmith@company.com"
srchSubject = EmailSubject

Set Itms = Itms.Restrict("[SenderName] = "BobSmith@company.com" And 
[Subject] = EmailSubject And [SentOn] > '" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & 
"'")

If Itms.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No " & srchSubject & " email on " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
End If

Set Itms = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: An easier approach might be to setup an outlook rule that specifies the logic to move that item to a specific folder. At that point then you can sort the folder and check if the first item is for today.

Comment: Hey Ryan, good idea. Did that and have it working great! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Likely wrong format for srchSender and combining a filter, for me, requires a confusing sequence of matching quotes.

```
Private Sub ReminderUnreceivedMail()

Dim Itms As items
Dim srchSender As String
Dim srchSubject As String

Dim strFilterBuild As String
Dim ItmsBuild As items

Dim strFilter As String
Set Itms = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).items

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Itms.count
    Debug.Print Itms(i).senderName
Next

srchSender = "what you see in senderName from the above"
srchSubject = "EmailSubject"

' If you cannot get the quotes right all at once, build the filter.
strFilterBuild = "[SenderName] = '" & srchSender & "'"
Debug.Print strFilterBuild

Set ItmsBuild = Itms.Restrict(strFilterBuild)
If ItmsBuild.count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No " & srchSender & " email."
    GoTo ExitRoutine
End If

strFilterBuild = strFilterBuild & " And [Subject] = '" & srchSubject & "'"
Debug.Print strFilterBuild

Set ItmsBuild = Itms.Restrict(strFilterBuild)
If ItmsBuild.count = 0 Then
    ' This should find old mail
    MsgBox "No " & srchSender & " email with subject " & srchSubject
    GoTo ExitRoutine
End If

strFilterBuild = strFilterBuild & " And [SentOn] > '" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
Debug.Print strFilterBuild

Set ItmsBuild = Itms.Restrict(strFilterBuild)
If ItmsBuild.count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No " & srchSender & " email with subject " & srchSubject & " today"
    GoTo ExitRoutine
End If

' This should match the final strFilterBuild to confirm it can be done all at once.
strFilter = "[SenderName] = '" & srchSender & "' And [Subject] = '" & srchSubject & "' And [SentOn] > '" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
Debug.Print strFilter

Set Itms = Itms.Restrict(strFilter)
If Itms.count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No " & srchSubject & " email on " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
End If

ExitRoutine:
    Set Itms = Nothing

End Sub
```