# Outlook Macro that saves attachments from messages from specific people/with specific title beginning

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to write an Outlook macro that saves attachments from mails which have specified title beginnings (for example: "Report..") OR have specified senders.
I haven't programmed in Outlook VBA, so i don't know how to begin. Can you help?

Comment: You need to show what did you try and wasn't working for you, otherwise the question is too broad. The following may be the start: [Save attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531093/save-attachments-to-a-folder-and-rename-them/15532110) and [Search for Outlook Email based on Sender, Subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927567/search-for-outlook-email-based-on-sender-subject-and-todays-date). Please do you research first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43080675/4539709

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you want.

```
Sub SetFlagIcon()

Const olFolderInbox = 6

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set colItems = objFolder.Items

For Each objMessage In colItems
If objMessage.SenderEmailAddress = "someone@gmail.com" Then
    intCount = objMessage.Attachments.Count
    If intCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To intCount
            objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile "C:\your_path_here\Desktop\" & _
                objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
        Next
    End If
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Please see the links below for some other ideas of where to go with this.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3747-outlook-auto-download-save-attachments-to-folder.html

https://www.pixelchef.net/content/rule-autosave-attachment-outlook